# How can I filter items in DjangoRestFramework?

Tags: python, django, api, filter, django-rest-framework

I am complete beginner and I made a django project a while ago. Its main purpose is adding restaurants and categories and food menu respectively. For now, it is working well, if I go to the required restaurant, it shows its categories. But now, I want to improve it via Vuejs and that's why I'm trying to make Django REST API. But I can't filter categories and food according to their restaurant, because category model is not directly connected to restaurant model. My models.py is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="restaurant", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='logos/', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='categories/', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Food(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, related_name='foods', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='foods', on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='foods/', blank=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

As you see, category class is not directly connected to restaurant. It is filtered with views.py. My views.py is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Restaurant, Category, Food


def food_list(request, restaurant_slug, category_slug):
    restaurant = get_object_or_404(Restaurant, slug=restaurant_slug)
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    foods = Food.objects.filter(restaurant=restaurant, category=category, available=True)
    categories = set(list(Category.objects.filter(foods__restaurant=restaurant)))
    return render(request, 'restaurant/food_list.html', {'restaurant': restaurant, 'category': category, 'foods': foods, 'categories': categories})

def category_list(request, restaurant_slug=None):
    restaurant = get_object_or_404(Restaurant, slug=restaurant_slug)
    categories = set(list(Category.objects.filter(foods__restaurant=restaurant)))
    return render(request, 'restaurant/category_list.html', {'restaurant': restaurant, 'categories': categories})
```

As I mentioned above it is working well now. But I want to GET categories and food respect to their restaurants. How to filter it with Django REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Example code of filtering in Django :

```
class PassengerList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Passenger
    serializer_class = PassengerSerializer

    # Show all of the PASSENGERS in particular WORKSPACE
    # or all of the PASSENGERS in particular AIRLINE
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Passenger.objects.all()
        workspace = self.request.query_params.get('workspace')
        airline = self.request.query_params.get('airline')

        if workspace:
            queryset = queryset.filter(workspace_id=workspace)
        elif airline:
            queryset = queryset.filter(workspace__airline_id=airline)

        return queryset
```